# Python: Take URL from list and access it

Tags: python, list, for-loop, twill

I'm trying to take a URL from a list (~1500 entries) and access them one by one using the **twill** lib for python. The reason that I'm using twill is because I like it and I might have to perform basic formfilling later on.

The problem I have is declaring the contents of the loop.
I'm sure this is actually pretty simple to solve, but the solution just won't come to my mind at the moment.

```
            from twill.commands import *
            CONTAINER = open('urls.txt') #opening file
            CONTAINER_CONTENTS = CONTAINER.readlines() #reading
            CONTAINER_CONTENTS = map(lambda s: s.strip, CONTAINER_CONTENTS) #this is just to remove the ^N (newline) that was appended to each URL

            for i in CONTAINER_CONTENTS:
                  <educate me>
                  ..
                  go(url)
                  etc.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from twill.commands import *

with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        go(url)
        # now do something with the page
```

Comment: A helpful reference: [Language Constructs you Should Not Use: `from module import *`](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).